# MySQL - Filter based on the first character of a column in a select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, string, where-clause

Names:

```
Watts, Odysseus D.
Schultz, Wilma D. 
Mckinney, Madaline R.  
Charles, Mohammad O.
```

My table names like this structure, first_name and last_name are in single column called names, i want to get all names from starting with letter 'M' in their last name,

How to write in mysql query for this criteria???

Answer (score 2):

If the last name appears at the beginning of the string, the you can just do:

```
select * from names where name like 'M%'
```

On the other hand, if you want to filter on the first character after the comma, then:

```
select * from names where name like '%, M%'
```